# Making a Javascript variable remain same in all pages

Tags: javascript

I am using an external javascript file in two pages. I change the value of a variable from the first page. Now when I use the second page, the value of that variable goes back to its initialisation value. I want to maintain the value of the variable. How can I do this?

```
var mail="not yet added";
```

I change this value in page 1 to "xxxxxx@xxxx.com".
Now when I access this in page 2 I get "not yet added"

Comment: Use `localStorage` or `cookies`

Comment: or even both(ie: cookie as fallback)

Comment: Or use `window.name` ;-) (Since that holds a string value only, you might have to serialize your value before if it's a more complex value, f.e. by encoding it as JSON.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `windows.name` object as long as you're in the same windows or tab. Have look [here](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html).

Otherwise the [persists.js framework](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js) offers a number of different ways to persist information and share it between pages etc.

Your final option is of course using a basic cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a cookie on javascript, otherwise post the value back to the server (i.e. php or whatever you are using) - then you can print the variable explicitly on the next JS page if thats easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass variable to second page by adding #hash to link then in second page just retrieve it and update the variable with hash value.